# Como agregar una nueva columna a una tabla en Postgresql con el valor de otra columna de la misma tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql, transact-sql

Necesito agregar una nueva columna a una tabla de tipo timestamp con el valor now() por
defecto, pero para los registros que ya existen se tiene que almacenar el valor de otra columna igual de tipo fecha de la misma tabla. Posterior a eso ya los nuevos registros se iran registrando con la fecha del servidor

**Ejemplo**

table_ejemplo

| id | name | date1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maria | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | Luis | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |

Resultado

| id | name | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maria | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | Luis | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar la columna necesaria y luego hacer el update pertinente:

```
    CREATE TABLE table_ejemplo (id int , name text, date1 timestamp);
    INSERT INTO table_ejemplo VALUES (1,'maria','2022-02-01 00:00:00'),(2,'luis','2022-02-01 00:00:00'),(3,'fecha vacia',null);
    ALTER TABLE table_ejemplo ADD COLUMN date2 timestamp default now();
   
    --actualizo el valor de date2 donde date1 no sea null
    UPDATE table_ejemplo SET date2=date1 WHERE date1 is not null
```

Y ya los nuevo registro tendran su fecha nueva por el `default`